# Data Representation

Tags: python, representation

We can implement decimal to binary conversion for positive integers in Python by using the following algorithm that takes an integer n as input and returns a string of 1's and 0's holding the binary representation of n .

Write a function int_to_bin_string(n) (in int_to_bin_string.py) which takes a non-negative integer n and returns the a string of 1's and 0's.

We are not allowed to use any built in python functions that converts numbers to strings or vice versa.

```
    def int_to_bin_string(n):
        if n == 0:
            return "0"
        s = ''
        while n > 0:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                ch = "0"
            else:
                ch = "1"
            s = s + ch
            n = n/2
        return s
```

That's what I have tried. When I try int_to_bin_string(255) I get '1', instead of '11111111'

**It works now!**

Comment: I fixed n/2 to n = n/2, that was an oversight. It still only gives me '1'

Comment: Is this python3?  If so, you probably want `n = n // 2`

Comment: If you are getting "chchchchchchchchchch", you probably did `s = s + "ch"` instead of `s = s + ch`.

Comment: I got a Syntaxerror when I took out the single quotes saying : can't assign to literal

Comment: Pretty sure you're not running the code you posted here.

Comment: You're right I was modifying according to what people suggested. I went back to what was posted and now it's saying global name 'ch' is not defined.

Comment: @user2833230: I just copied & pasted the code from the question, ran it, and then ran `print int_to_bin_string(255)`.  I got `11111111` and no errors.  You're not running the code you're asking about.

Comment: This is what happens when you modify the code in the original question.  Next time, have a separate update section with a new version of the code, so that people can see what is going on.

Comment: The thing I'm confused about is where you got the idea to put quotes around the `ch`... that was never suggested in the below answers or comments.

Answer (score 1):

for the second to last line, you need to have

```
n = n/2
```

Comment: Also put the `return` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a premature return in return s.  It needs to be outside your while loop, which is why you are getting only one character.  Also it should be n = n/2.

Additionally, look at your first return statement, it returns an integer instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a key function of python

```
bin( value ) # returns a string like '0b110110'
```

simply get a slice if you only want the numbers...
`bin( value )[2:]`

Comment: we're not allowed to use built in python functions

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of writing it yourself. Also, the question states that you cannot use builtin functions to do this.

Comment: sorry... some in fact do post such questions without knowing the capability of the language they use.
well then i refer to the other answers...
n=n/2
and
return outside the loop

Comment: I fixed that, but now it returns a bunch of "chchchchchchchchchchchchcH" etc

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative for you... it's almost the same though

```
def int_to_bin_string(n):
    s = ''
    while n:        
        s = ((n & 1) and "1" or "0") + s
        n >>= 1
    return s or "0"
```

I hope this does help ;)

Comment: i must admit that i can't see the reason why you are getting a string like "chchchchchchchchchch" when you didn't add additional quotation :/

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet a nickel, from the symptoms, that this is a Python 3 vs. Python 2 issue.  Your code as modified works fine on Python 2.

You can make this code bilingual with a simple modification.  Replace the division by 2 with a shift.  In place of `n = n/2`, use `n = n>>1`.  That works on both P2 and P3.

```
def int_to_bin_string(num):
    n = int(num) # added to force int type on entry
    if n == 0:
        return "0"
    s = ''
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            ch = "0"
        else:
            ch = "1"
        s = s + ch
        n = n >> 1 # was n/2
    return s
```

I also added a small filter to coerce the argument to int on entry, with a rename to avoid losing the original argument value. When debugging, I like see the original value--hence the rename.  I just do that as  reflex; it's not related to your question.